# calling mount() system call as a non-root user

Tags: c++, c, linux, permissions, mount

I am writing a C/C++ program that needs to be able to mount a disk as an ordinary user (can't run with `sudo`). Typically, questions of this type pertain to using the `mount` command in a shell, and the answer is to use the "user" option in the `/etc/fstab` entry corresponding to the disk in question. However, I don't think that the listings in the `/etc/fstab` matter at all when using the mount system call in a program.

However, since it is clear that the `mount` command is capable of allowing non-root users to mount disks (assuming the `/etc/fstab` is setup right), and presumably the mount command calls the `mount` system call, then I think it should be possible to achieve what I want.

How can I successfully call the `mount()` system call without running the program with `sudo`?

Comment: The reason `mount` can do it, is because `mount` is a setuid root program. Your "C/C++ program" must be executed with root privileges. Technically, as Linux [man pages specifies](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/mount.2.html), the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` privilege is required. A regular user process cannot mount filesystems.

Comment: There is no C/C++ language, there is C and there is C++.

Comment: But because `mount` is a setuid root program, you can just run it, _without_ sudo, and as long as the `/etc/fstab` settings are correct, it will do what you want.

Comment: @Pablo There are plenty of C/C++ programs though, and that's the phrase being used.

Answer (score 0):

A valid solution to this dilemma is to pack the `mount`/`umount` calls into a shell script, provide `sudo` permissions for that to the application user, and call it from the application e. g. using `system()`. Make sure that the script does adequate error handling and perhaps logging, returning the appropriate exit code on error or success you can handle in the calling application.

`/etc/sudoers.d/myApplication`:

```
<appUser> <host> = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/myMountScript.sh
```

In your application:

```
const int result = system("sudo /usr/local/bin/myMountScript.sh <options>");
//Error handling on result follows below
```

Another possibility is to use capabilities, as mentioned in a comment above, and set them on the binary, but that's bit more complex, so I don't get into details here.

Comment: *A valid solution to this dilemma is to pack the `mount`/`umount` calls into a shell script, provide sudo permissions for that to the application user, and call it from the application e. g. using system().*  That's a **dangerous**-to-the-security-of your-system solution.  For example, your `system("sudo /usr/local/bin/myMountScript.sh <options>");` will run the `sudo` executable specified by the *user's* `PATH` envval as `root`.

Comment: That's exactly what any `sudo` call does. Where exactly do you see the issue?

Comment: Off the top of my head: instant root shell:  `mkdir ~/bin; ln -s /bin/bash ~/bin/sudo; PATH=~/bin /path/to/yourBinary` Unless you configure things really carefully, using `system()` is extremely dangerous in any privileged program.  You're much better off just calling [the `mount()` function directly](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html).  You pretty much have to hardcode it anyway.

Comment: What about hardcoding `/usr/bin/sudo` in the `system()` call?